# Why is tan(x-1)/(x-1) defined in x=1?

Tags: calculus, limits

The title explains it. We have (x-1) in the denominator which leads to the conclusion that the function is not defined in x=1. However I used an online graph plotter and the function is defined at x=1, in fact f(1)=1.
Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: The graph is not defined at $x=1$. It merely appears to be because the limit from either side of this point is $1$.

Comment: but desmos doesn't show that

Comment: You can however show that $\color{blue}{\lim\limits_{x\to 1}}\frac{\tan (x-1)}{x-1}=1$. Try also plotting for example $y = x/x$, which is undefined at $0$ but has an obvious limit there.

Comment: I think you'll find if you click at the exact point where $x=1$ Desmos will say the graph is undefined.

Comment: TRUE, it's not highlighted though. For a minute there i questioned my knowledge of basic maths. Thanks homie

Comment: @PeterForeman It doesn't happen for [this function](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zcec6bb9s7). I think the only way is add an open point at the discontinuity manually.

Comment: Yes it does. I don't know what you are talking about. Just click on the point where $x=1$

Comment: @TobyMak, I clicked through on your link, and when I managed to click my cursor at exactly $x=1$, it said "(1,undefined)," just as Peter Foreman reported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right: the function is not defined at $x=1$ because division by $0$ is undefined.

However, some online graphers such as Desmos do not automatically plot point discontinuties. You can add an open point manually as shown in [here](https://support.desmos.com/hc/en-us/articles/209253246-Point-Discontinuity-Open-Point).

Comment: Although Desmos does find point discontinuities which can be seen by hovering over the given coordinate.